# Is it okay to rephrase my question without programming, on a different SE?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

Imagine I were to ask a question about calculating when circles will collide in JavaScript. It's barely seen at all; it's an important issue, and I can't really wait 2 days for a bounty. If I rephrase it mathematically, it might be answerable by math people.

So, if I were to rephrase my question without JavaScript and just ask about the *mathematical* process, would it be okay to post a near-identical question on another SE site?

This is probably a dupe, but I couldn't find any specific to something like this.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYzA_kPWyJ8

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Techniques/2D_collision_detection

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript/Collision_detection

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440377

Comment: And yes, I know some of these links contain code.  Code examples are one of the best ways to understand something, and they already contain the necessary math.

Comment: Anyway, the first link talks about the math.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the help, but I unfortunately phrased my question badly it seems. My mathematical question was about detecting when they would collide on a certain trajectory, and I simplified it quite a bit here as it was not relevant. Sorry if I wasted your time, but thanks anyway!

Comment: The math is still very similar.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Yes, but they aren't heading towards each other. One is at a different angle.

Comment: *"[How to Code: Collision Detection — Part I](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XYzA_kPWyJ8)"* (the link in the first comment) is part of playlist *"[HTML5 Canvas Tutorials for Beginners | Become a Canvas Pro](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpPnRKq7eNW3We9VdCfx9fprhqXHwTPXL)"* (8 parts).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I know how to use a canvas...I'm not stupid. If it doesn't contribute to _this meta question_, there is no reason to comment.